# How can I check if base64 encoding is correct?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am base64 encoding a transactionReciept for in-App purchasing verification.  I encode in my app and post it to my server, then send to sandbox.  I am getting status:21002.  How do I check my encoded receipt to insure that the encoding is correct?

This is what we are sending to the sandbox:

"receipt-data" : "uPOMP4QUAAIKCgAACgoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB7Cgkic2lnbmF0dXJlIiA9ICJBaW9DWFhqeUpKeStUc29wZkJIUGE2bkxDS0hHbnNqbE5iRTlrTE1kYVJ2STZDTnIzVlQ5QlVBZE5GRlFwRmM5d0doN1N2bHJH.......", "password" : "cKWOP8gHAABhyAYAIAA...."

Does this look like a base64 encode? Do we have the name-value pairs correct?  We just send a receipt and a password as name-value pairs, right?

Thanks.

Comment: On one online base64 decoder I get "?�

��

������������������{
 "signature" = "AioCXXjyJJy+TsopfBHPa6nLCKHGnsjlNbE9kLMdaRvI6CNr3VT9BUAdNFFQpFc9wGh7SvlrG" when I try to decode that -- I suspect that something's wrong.  At the very least the long string of "A" characters is odd.

Comment: Base64 decoder here: http://www.base64decode.org/

Comment: Do I have to change the HEX receipt to ASCII before I encode?  "signature" should probably be the first name/value pair in the receipt, though.

Comment: You can base64 encode "pure binary" (which I suppose is what you mean by "hex") -- this is the main reason for using base64 in the first place.  Unfortunately, however, the referenced online encoder/decoder will not work with pure binary data very well.  (You may be able to find one that will accept a binary file or a hex string somewhere.)

Comment: Note that it's easy to accidentally get some extra characters in the binary data -- carriage returns or space characters, eg.  And you need to be careful with lengths, if the target site can't tolerate "junk" on the end of the string.  Also note that there may be zero to 3 (IIRC) "=" characters on the end of the encoded string as pad characters -- these are "significant" and need to be included with the rest.

Comment: Thanks to all.  My encoding was faulty.  I was using some copied code that didn't work.  Found some good code and all is well.